# Is the accuracy of Whirlwind not affected by moves such as Flash?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

Was doing a status moves only challenge in Pokémon Blue and trying to catch a wild Pidgey or Pidgeotto. They kept chasing me away with Whirlwind, so I thought I would try to mitigate that by putting them to sleep and using Flash. However, even after hitting them with Flash 6 times, they seem to always hit Whirlwind. I have not seen them miss even once. Is Whirlwind not affected by Flash?

Answer (score 4):

Whirlwind is affected by accuracy and evasion like most other moves. Since Whirlwind's base accuracy is 85%, it still has a 21% chance of landing after using Flash 6 times.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I must simply have had back luck!

Comment: Worth noting that in a later generation, Whirlwind bypasses accuracy checks. Also note that these numbers are true when the user's level is at least the target's level -- when the user is lower level, the probability is lower.

Comment: Are both you guys sure that this also applies when wild Pokémon use the move? @Schism

Comment: I did some trials and I saw wild Pidgeotto use Whirlwind over 30 times. It did not miss even once. I constantly used Flash and Double Team, and many of the Whirlwinds hit even after I got off 6 Flash and Double Team. Are you guys absolutely sure? @Schism

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. First you said Whirlwind didn't miss even once, then you said "many of the Whirlwinds hit". Which is it?

Comment: @Wrigglenite Sorry, miswrote. Every single one hit.